# Dojo Localization - data-dojo-props fails when localised string contains single quote

Tags: javascript, localization, dojo

I'm attempting to localize a dojo template and I'm hitting an issue when the localized string contains a single quote.

My template looks something like this:

```
<div>
    <select data-dojo-props="label:'${i18n.mySelectorLabel}'"
            >
    </select>
</div>
```

and the associated line in the resource bundle for the French language looks something like this:

```
"mySelectorLabel" : "d'élément :",
```

It was my expectation that the dojo templating system would cope with the single quote, present in the French word for 'element', without additional escaping in the resource bundle.

Executing my code results in the following error:

```
dojo/parser::parse() error Error: SyntaxError: Expected '}' in data-dojo-props='label:'d'élément :''
```

Clearly the single quote hasn't been appropriately escaped, but I'm not sure where my mistake lies.  It would seem odd to have to escape the single quote inside the string in the resource bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at how the dojo parser works, it would appear that it passes value of the data-dojo-props attribute into eval.  You end up with something like this:

```
eval("{" + "label:'${i18n.mySelectorLabel}'" + "}");
```

This would seem to imply that the issue outlined in the question is a fundamental limitation of dojo.

The workaround proposed by vogomatix works for the ' character specifically, but is affected by the minifier in use.  Uglify is fine, but Dojo ShrinkSafe is not.

With those points in mind, the solutions we came up with are as follows:

1. Escape the character in the resource bundle.
2. Set label explicitly
   `<select label="${i18n.mySelectorLabel}">`
3. Use an attach point to set the label programmatically.

We went with option 2.  Not ideal but demonstrated as working on both Dojo 1.7 with Dojo ShrinkSafe and Dojo 1.10 with Uglify.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to throw this out there speculatively. Try reversing the use of single and double quotes in the template:

```html
<div>
  <select data-dojo-props='label:"${i18n.mySelectorLabel}"'>
  </select>
</div>
```

**Update:** Unfortunately this doesn't work all the time either - see comments by OP for further explanation.

Comment: That works in our specific case (thank you!), but I wonder if there is a more general solution?  Having reversed the quote usage, the string now couldn't contain a double quote.  Clearly that is less likely to occur, but it demonstrates that in reality we've just worked around the issue rather than found a solution.

Comment: Digging a bit deeper, it would appear that dojo passes the props value into eval.  You end up with something like this:

eval("{" + "label:'${i18n.mySelectorLabel}'" + "}");

From this, it would appear that the issue outlined in the question is a fundamental limitation of dojo and the only real solution is to escape the characters in the resource bundle.

Comment: Actually, I take it back, the proposed solution doesn't work in our case.  Whether it works or not is affected by the minifier being used.  This solution works if Uglify is used as the minifier, but not if Dojo ShrinkSafe is used.  In our case, this has popped up in an old project that uses the latter.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I didn't have access to Dojo at the time. You ought to submit and accept your own answer as you're one of the few who does put the effort in if you don't get the right answer :D